# Jenkins sends email notification to all SVN users

Tags: email, jenkins

I have a build job that cleans, builds, and tests our project. I have setup Jenkins to send an email to me + the developer who broke the build. We then had one developer break a test so that the test did not compile. Jenkins sent an email notification to everyone registered to SVN.

We all work on the same branch, but shouldn't Jenkins only notify me + the one developer who broke the build? I understand that all developers who have touched the code AFTER the build has broken should also be notified, but according to SVN logs there was only one person doing the commit. Jenkins polls SVN right away after a commit has been made, so there were no subsequent commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using "Editable Email Notification" post-build action?
If you don't see that option, you may need to download "email-ext" plugin
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

Once you've selected the plugin in the post-build section, you then have an "advanced" button. Click that, and you will see an option to "Add a trigger". You have triggers for things such as:
- "Success" (Successful build) or 
- "Failure" (failed build). 
- There is also a trigger for "Unstable" builds. If you are running Maven, failed tests usually mark the build unstable, or there are other ways you can manually mark builds unstable based on conditions.

Either way, for each trigger, you can specify to whom to send the email (and you can have multiple triggers configured).

Recipient list - predefined list, either global or per trigger
Committers - those that made SVN changes for this checkout
Culprits - those that made SVN changes since last successful build
Requester - user that triggers the build