# Start Job as latest user having commited

Tags: svn, jenkins, hudson

I am currently using **[Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)** to automate our build and testing process.
Every 30 minutes, Jenkins will poll our svn server and check for new commits.

If a new commit if found, the new code is downloaded, and then several ant tasks are fired to generate our products.

In case the build fails, I want **the person responsible for the latest svn commit** to be notified by mail.
Thing is, my job always starts with :

```
Started by user anonymous
```

that redirects to user/null, making it impossible to know who to send a mail to.

How can I do so that the mail is sent **to the latest svn commiter?**

Thanks, 
Julien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally seem to have found my answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006244/jenkins-sends-email-notification-to-all-svn-users).here

I use the [email ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin).

Maybe this can help someone some day :)

Comment: Does the jenkins manual mentions the email plugin anywhere? As a total Jenkins newbie I searched the manual first, and for some time before posting. Some feel free to point the right direction if you want :).

Comment: The "Use Jenkins" page lists lots of helpful resources for installing and using Jenkins. It also contains the link to the Jenkins Plugins page. The third link on jenkins-ci.org points to the plugin page. The description states "Choose from over 600 plugins to customize Jenkins exactly to your needs." The plugin page contains the email extension plugin. So to answer your question: Yes, it's mentioned in the manual.